# Remove some blank spaces from a complicated string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

i have these strings:

```
14/04/22 10:45:20 12.08N 87.65W 15.0 2.9ML Frente a Corinto
14/04/21 11:05:34 12.10N 87.70W 140.0 3.5MC Cerca de Masachapa
14/04/22 09:00:09  12.35N  86.44W  12.4  1.3ML Cerca del volcan Momotombo
14/04/21 23:33:37  12.35N  86.63W   7.1  1.0ML SO de La Paz Centro/Nagarote
```

and i want to convert them to this:

```
14/04/22-10:45:20-12.08N-87.65W-15.0-2.9ML-Frente a Corinto
14/04/21-11:05:34-12.10N-87.70W-140.0-3.5MC-Cerca de Masachapa
14/04/22-09:00:09-12.35N-86.44W-12.4-1.3ML-Cerca del volcan Momotombo
14/04/21-23:33:37-12.35N-86.63W-7.1-1.0ML-SO de La Paz Centro/Nagarote
```

Someone can help me to do it with Regular Expressions in Javascript?

Thanks !

PD: Edited. OK, let me be more especific: I want to replace all white spaces with "-", except those spaces before a letter, but also replace the white space before the first appearance of a letter in the beginning of a word. Please, look my example above to understand what i need.

Comment: Define your replacement rules clearly

Comment: So it's always up until `Frente` that you want to replace spaces with hyphens ?

Comment: that means that `Frente` it will be a constant?

Comment: Nope, `Frente` is not a constant. I just want to replace all blank spaces, except for the last words in the string, i mean between the last words in the string.

Comment: But `Frente a` has no last word?

Comment: hmmm so how come this part `Frente a Masachapa` has not `-`?

Comment: This is making less and less sense? How would you know what the last words are if there is no constant ?

Comment: @robe007 mate that is what his regx is doing, adding `-` except in the last sentence.... also my function is working as that... put it in spanish if you feel you can explain it better that way..

Comment: Yes, but his regx don't add also **-** at the beginning of the last sentence, and this is what i want too.

Comment: @robe007 so dont use regx and use my function?

Comment: Yes, your function works, but i want to know how to do it with regx (to practice, you know)  (:

Comment: @robe007 yeah, the problem is that there is not constant data, and regx depends on that.. the only one I could think of was using `match(/\d+/g)` which takes whatever it has a integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use lookahead regex like this:

```
var s = '14/04/21 23:33:37  12.35N  86.63W   7.1  1.0ML SO de La Paz Centro/Nagarote';

var r = s.replace(/ +(?![A-Za-z])/g, '-').replace(/ (?=[a-zA-Z])/, '-');
//=> 14/04/21-23:33:37-12.35N-86.63W-7.1-1.0ML-SO de La Paz Centro/Nagarote
```

Comment: +1 good one, but i totally dont get it.. :D can you explain it a bit?

Comment: @jycr753 - replaces all spaces but the two last spaces

Comment: @jycr753: Added a brief explanation

Comment: @anubhava and adeneo, thanks :) It makes sense now, but i bet his data will screw up, since there 3 more ways to say that in spanish..

Comment: Ok, not solves the problem, the last part of string not always has 2 spaces, the string could be like this too: `14/04/22 09:00:09  12.35N  86.44W  12.4  1.3ML Cerca del volcan Momotombo` and like this `14/04/21 23:33:37  12.35N  86.63W   7.1  1.0ML SO de La Paz Centro/Nagarote`

Comment: In that case read my very first comment again & respond: **Define your replacement rules clearly**

Comment: When should there be single space in the end and when should be multiple?

Comment: @anubhava I just only want to replace all the white spaces from the string, except the white spaces from the last chars of the string. I mean, except the white spaces between the last chars of the string.

Comment: @anubhava I know that sometimes, there are single spaces and sometimes multiple spaces, but only in the first part of the string, not between the last chars where i want to not be replaced.

Comment: How would any code know how many spaces in the end should not be replaced?

Comment: @anubhava OK, let me be more especific: I want to remove all white spaces, except those spaces before a letter.

Comment: Nope, does not work with these strings: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23228718/remove-some-blank-spaces-from-a-complicated-string-in-javascript#comment35538743_23228889)

Comment: 1. Code or data in comments is useless can't be read. 2. It follows your own rule that said: `I want to remove all white spaces, except those spaces before a letter`

Comment: Ok, i know, it works, but i think i was a little wrong when i said `I want to remove all white spaces, except those spaces before a letter`. I mean, i really want this, except for the beginning of the last part of the string, i mean this: `SO de La Paz Centro/Nagarote` and `Cerca del volcan Momotombo`

Comment: If i have this string: `14/04/22 09:00:09  12.35N  86.44W  12.4  1.3ML Cerca del volcan Momotombo` i want this result: `14/04/22-09:00:09-12.35N-86.44W-12.4-1.3ML-Cerca del volcan Momotombo`

Comment: Despite my repeated comments your replacement logic is not clear your requirement is still vague and unclear. Whatever your requirement is you need to make it clear in your question (not it comments) I will not make any further edit as it is not making sense.

Comment: @anubhava sorry my friend, but thanks for your help, i updated my question, i hope this time you can understand what i need.

Comment: You're most welcome. Love that **धन्यवाद** in hindi :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51300/discussion-between-robe007-and-anubhava)

Answer (score 2):

How's this? Very simple. It's just assuming you only want to replace up to the second space that is followed by a letter:

```
"14/04/22 10:45:20 12.08N 87.65W 15.0 2.9ML Frente a Corinto".replace(/\s(?=\d)/g, '-').replace(/ /, '-')
"14/04/22-10:45:20-12.08N-87.65W-15.0-2.9ML-Frente a Corinto"
```

Comment: Great solution! But use **\s+** in both of your replaces, because as you can see, some of the inputs have more than one space in a row.

Answer (score 1):

If regex alone are not working as you want, this code it may be the right thing for you, since we use regex to get any string that contains numbers on it, since in this case this is the only constant in the data, from there we store all data in a temporal array and when is done we generated the desire output.

```
function formatString(str) {
    var ss = str.split(' ');
    var listItems = [];
    var listStrings = [];
    var finalStringInt = "";
    var finalStringStr = "";

    for (var t = 0; t < ss.length; t ++) {
        var matchNumer = ss[t].match(/\d+/g);
        if(matchNumer != null){
            listItems.push(ss[t]);
        }else{
            listStrings.push(ss[t]);
        }

    }
    for (var sx = 0; sx < listItems.length; sx++) {
        finalStringInt += listItems[sx]+"-";
    }

    for (var xx = 0; xx < listStrings.length; xx++) {
        finalStringStr += listStrings[xx]+" ";
    }

    return finalStringInt.trim() + finalStringStr.trim(); 
}

var s="14/04/21 23:33:37  12.35N  86.63W   7.1  1.0ML SO de La Paz Centro/Nagarote";
console.log(formatString(s));
```

output::

```
14/04/22-10:45:20-12.08N-87.65W-15.0-2.9ML-Frente a Corinto
14/04/22-09:00:09-12.35N-86.44W-12.4-1.3ML-Cerca del volcan Momotombo
```

Comment: @robe007 no problem mate, this is why we have this community :) plus i like helping people from my own country ;)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regex at all:

```
var s="14/04/22 10:45:20 12.08N 87.65W 15.0 2.9ML Frente a Corinto";
s = s.split(' ', 6).join('-');
console.log(s);
```

output:

```
14/04/22-10:45:20-12.08N-87.65W-15.0-2.9ML
```

This will replace the six first spaces in the string.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying edit jycr753. Dont know why my phone wont let me format code correctly...

Comment: I like this solution, but there is something wrong.  You said it would replace the first 6 spaces, but your output has only 5 spaces replaced.

Comment: @MattiasÅslund No problem. yes it is a good solution, even tho you only need to split until 7, so you get something like `14/04/22-10:45:20-12.08N-87.65W-15.0-2.9ML-Frente` but is eating the rest of the sentence..